# Chromium won't recognise woff fonts despite declaring application/x-font-woff as the MIME type

Tags: google-chrome, mime-types, woff

I have declared `AddType application/x-font-woff woff`but chromium still always give me the message `Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream`. What is going on here, it seems to be a rather common problem. This is Chrome version 14 by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually a legitimate bug in chrome at the time of posting, not sure if it still exists and can't find the relevant link to chrome bug list. If anyone is interested that'd be the first place to look.

Comment: This seems to be the case, the same thing happens even for fonts served from google web fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but a possible answer for future visitors:

Chrome caches the heck out of things - even when you change the header from the server, Chrome may still load the resource from it's cache. So clear the cache and if necessary, check the headers from a realtime web-checking service.